# Javascript - How to use nested for loop to create table?

Tags: javascript

Below is the Javascript Code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJKhi.png)

```
<script language = "javascript" >
  var sout;
sout = "<table border='1' width='300' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>"
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  sout = sout + "<tr>";
  for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
    sout = sout + "<td>" + i * j + "</td>";
  }
  sout = sout + "</tr>";
}
sout = sout + "</table>";
document.write(sout); </script>
```

Comment: Please post some code and tell us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a moment and read [ask] and create [mcve] of your code and explain what is the part you are struggling with.

Comment: <script language="javascript">
var sout;
sout = "<table border='1' width='300' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>"
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
sout = sout + "<tr>";
for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
sout = sout + "<td>" + i * j + "</td>";
}
sout = sout + "</tr>";
}
sout = sout + "</table>";
document.write (sout);
</script>

Comment: Edit the code to the ***question*** not in comments, also elaborate what is not working as you intend.

Comment: so sorry, i am new guy

Comment: my problem is how to change the last two row become like first two row

Comment: and also how to highlight yellow color like that picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this code

```
    var sout;
    var increase = true;
    sout = "<table border='1' width='300' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>"
    for (i = 1; i <= 3 && i >= 1;) {
        sout = sout + "<tr>";

        for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
            if (i*j % 3 == 0)
                sout = sout + "<td style='text-align: center; background-color:yellow'>" + i * j + "</td>";
            else 
                sout = sout + "<td style='text-align: center'>" + i * j + "</td>";

        }

        if (i < 3  && increase)
          i++;
        else if (i == 3)
        {
          increase = false;
          i--;
        }
        else
          i--;

        sout = sout + "</tr>";
    }
    sout = sout + "</table>";
    document.write(sout);
```